# Correct term for negative difference between two values

Tags: self-study, arithmetic

A very newbie question!

If the `absolute difference` between two values is the distance between them (and therefore always positive), what is the correct term for the distance between two values that does consider direction?

For example, if the average score in a test was 50 and my score was 45 the `absolute difference` would be 5, but this does not quantify my lack of intelligence!

Comment: What about a simple difference then? 50-45=5 would should how much worse you are than the average. Or 45-50=-5 would tell how much better you are than the average (-5 units better means 5 units worse).

Comment: It's just the difference, as @RichardHardy suggests. Working backwards, the reason we need to talk about absolute difference is to distinguish it from a difference, which in general can be positive, zero or negative.